# Can you set an initial size to a Virtualbox Dynamically Allocated Storage Drive?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I want to set the drive so it acts as a fixed drive up until a certain size and dynamically resizes after that point. For example, set the device so that it has 8GB to start with, and once it hits 8GB it dynamically resizes up to 20GB, which would be the size cap.

If that is not possible, then is is possible to set the size of the chunks of disk space added to the drive during resizing?